# Hovering over JSX attribute name shows unexpected type in tooltip. Bug or feature?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

When I hover the mouse over a JSX attribute in VS Code, the type shown in the IntelliSense tooltip is the type of the attribute value (the value that I put there) and not the prop type of the component (the type defined by the library author).

Type checking still works OK. If I try to put an incompatible type as that attribute's value, an error will be shown. So VS Code knows the expected type of the JSX attribute, it's just not showing it to me if the attribute has a valid value that's assignable to the prop type. (Yes, I realize that most of the time the value I use is going to be identical to the type that the library author specified, but they times when they don't match can introduce subtle bugs, which is why I was hovering to check the type of the attribute.)

Is this expected behavior?  If yes, why?

BTW, I know I can Go to Definition to look at the type in the library source code. So at least there's a workaround.

Here's repro steps.

1. Create React App with TypeScript (https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript)
2. Add this code to any TSX file:

   ```
   class Foo extends React.Component {

     handleClick = (event: any) => {
       console.log('clicked');
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <button onClick=></button>
       )
     }
   }
   ```
3. Hover the mouse over the attribute `onClick`.  The error message shows the type of the onClick prop as being `((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void) | undefined`

   ```
   [ts]
   Types of property 'onClick' are incompatible.
   Type 'true' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void) | undefined'.
   ----------------------------------------------
   (JSX attribute) onClick: true
   ```
4. Now add a value for the attribute, like this:

   ```
   <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
   ```
5. Hover the mouse over the onClick attribute again.

*Expected:* 
The **type of the prop in the component** (the same type shown in the error message in step 3 above). This type: `((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void) | undefined`

*Actual:* 
The **type of the attribute's value** is shown. This type: 
`(JSX attribute) onClick: (event: any) => void`

Is this a bug?  Or is it a feature?

If it matters, here's the extensions that I have installed:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+---------+
|         Extension         | Author (truncated) | Version |
+---------------------------+--------------------+---------+
| html-css-class-completion | Zig                | 1.17.1  |
| vscode-color              | ans                | 0.4.5   |
| npm-intellisense          | chr                | 1.3.0   |
| gitignore                 | cod                | 0.5.0   |
| vscode-eslint             | dba                | 1.4.12  |
| vscode-babel-coloring     | dza                | 0.0.4   |
| vscode-html-css           | ecm                | 0.2.0   |
| tslint                    | eg2                | 1.0.33  |
| vscode-npm-script         | eg2                | 0.3.5   |
| vscode-npm                | fkn                | 3.3.0   |
| auto-close-tag            | for                | 0.5.6   |
| auto-rename-tag           | for                | 0.0.15  |
| gitattributes             | has                | 0.4.1   |
| graphql-for-vscode        | kum                | 1.12.0  |
| node-module-intellisense  | lei                | 1.5.0   |
| mssql                     | ms-                | 1.4.0   |
| csharp                    | ms-                | 1.15.2  |
| node-debug2               | ms-                | 1.26.2  |
| debugger-for-chrome       | msj                | 4.8.0   |
| vscode-react-native       | vsm                | 0.6.12  |
| JavaScriptSnippets        | xab                | 1.7.0   |
| ReactSnippets             | xab                | 2.2.0   |
| propertylist              | zho                | 0.0.2   |
+---------------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

Comment: @Claies -  Are you saying that you see different behavior than I am seeing?  I have each of the extensions in the React Extension Pack installed separately (see extension list shown in my recent edit), except the "npm Intellisense" and "Search node_modules" extensions, neither of which should be affecting this behavior, right?

Comment: Slightly different note, but: shouldn't that be `<button onClick={ evt => this.onClick(evt) }></button>`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Nope. See https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html. You don't need to create a new function in React event handlers-- you can just point the JSX attribute for the handler at a function that you've already created.

Comment: Only if you follow their insane advice to explicitly `this.x = this.x.bind(this);` in the constructor  (which is unexpectedly bizarre advice from a team as experience as Facebook's React team. Those instructions shadow the prototype functions as local properties, increasing memory for no good reason). If you write a normal class, you want nice clear arrow notation in your handlers instead.